# Stack traces getting swallowed when developing VS Code Extensions

Tags: javascript, promise, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When my extension encounters an error, I'll often get a notification in the host environment saying that it encountered an error, but nothing gets printed to the debug console in the workspace of my extension. If I know the bug must be occurring in a given function, I can wrap all that function's code in a `try-catch` and then simply `console.log` the error in the `catch` statement. But that's a frustrating way to debug.

I'm pretty certain this is resulting from uncaught errors in promises, but I don't want to have to manually try catching ever one.

Any ideas on how to make sure I always get a stack trace?

Comment: You can add an unhandledRejection handler.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum can you clarify what you mean? The `window` object in a vs code extension doesn't have an `addEventListener` method, so something like this doesn't work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unhandledrejection